# Communication between 2 APIs that are inside two different containers

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have 2 REST APIs written in Python (3.6). They are both using Flask and Swagger. I build 2 docker images for each one of them. Then, run the 2 docker images like this:

```
$ docker run -d -p $HOST_PORT1:$APPLICATION_PORT1 --name $SERVICE_NAME1 $IMAGE1
$ docker run -d -p $HOST_PORT2:$APPLICATION_PORT2 --name $SERVICE_NAME2 $IMAGE2
```

They both run on the same machine. Let's say the ip of the machine is PUBLIC_IP.

When I try to access the API individually from a browser. It works just fine.
Using the PUBLIC_IP of the machine on which the containers are deployed and both the published ports. I can send queries and get right responses.

However, one endpoint of the first API, needs to call an endpoint of the other one. Here is how the first API is calling the second one:

```py
response = requests.post(url  = "http://PUBLIC_IP:APPLICATION_PORT2/v1/api/endpoint", 
                         json = {"data":s}).text
```

I target the PUBLIC_IP of the machine (both containers running on this machine). The call does not return. Here is the trace of the caller:

```
2020-05-01T18:08:39.670173821Z <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
2020-05-01T18:08:39.670190663Z  status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
2020-05-01T18:08:39.670202690Z  details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
2020-05-01T18:08:39.670217148Z  debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1588356519.668295801","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3981,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1588356519.668285228","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":394,"grpc_status":14}]}"
```

Comment: Without seeing exactly (a) how you're starting your docker containers and (b) how you're trying to access the api in one container from the other we can't really answer this question.

Comment: I run the two containers like this: `docker run -d -p 12555:12555 --name ws1 xxx.com:xxx/mypath1/img1:tag` and `docker run -d -p 12556:12556 --name ws2 xxx.com:xxx/mypath2/img2:tag` Those two images are build through gitlab-ci but I don't think this is relevant to the issue here. The two containers run on the same machine. I have a personal registry. That's why I put xxx insteas of real path

Comment: Unfortunately, you have elided critical information from your update: what ip address are you using in your argument to `requests.post`? Is that the ip address of your host? Of the other container? Something else? What port are you using? Have you verified that the target container is listening on the port to which you're trying to connect?

Comment: Both containers are running on the same machine. I am targeting them using the public IP of the host. The ports are both published. I am able to target each API from outside the container. Like in a browser. Things get messy when One API calls the other one (same machine but 2 different containers). Thanks for you answer below. You are mentioning the network command of docker that I never used before. I will study that more deeply.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that might be going on here. First, it looks like you're attempting to access the REST API in the other container by publishing the port on the host and then connecting to the published port. That should work, but it's not necessary; unless you really want to provide external access to that API it's better to have one container connect to the other directly. In this case, it's not necessary to publish the ports.

The easiest way to do this is to take advantage of the automatic DNS that docker provides on any network other than the default bridge network.  So if we first create a network named, say, `appnet`:

```
$ docker network create appnet
```

Then attach our containers to that network:

```
$ docker run -d --name container0 --network appnet alpinelinux/darkhttpd
$ docker run -d --name container1 --network appnet alpinelinux/darkhttpd
```

Then the containers can refer to eachother by name. For example, if I connect to `container0` I can access the web service running on `container1`:

```
$ docker exec -it container0 sh
/ $ wget -O- http://container1:8080
Connecting to container1:8080 (172.22.0.3:8080)
writing to stdout
<html>
<head>
 <title>/</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>/</h1>
<tt><pre>
<a href="..">..</a>/
</pre></tt>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Or, using `requests`:

```
$ docker exec -it -u root container0 sh
/ # apk add --update python3 py3-requests
/ # python3
>>> import requests
>>> res = requests.get('http://container1:8080')
>>> res.text
'<html>\n<head>\n <title>/</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h1>/</h1>\n<tt><pre>\n<a href="..">..</a>/\n</pre></tt>\n<hr>\n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

---

That said, publishing ports on your host should work just fine. For example, my host has address `192.168.1.200`.  If I start the containers like this instead:

```
$ docker run -d --name container0 -p 1234:8080 alpinelinux/darkhttpd
$ docker run -d --name container1 -p 4321:8080 alpinelinux/darkhttpd
```

Then I can access those services on the published host ports as expected:

```
$ docker exec -it container0 sh
/ $ wget -O- http://192.168.1.200:1234
Connecting to 192.168.1.200:1234 (192.168.1.200:1234)
writing to stdout
<html>
<head>
 <title>/</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>/</h1>
<tt><pre>
<a href="..">..</a>/
</pre></tt>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
/ $ wget -O- http://192.168.1.200:4321
Connecting to 192.168.1.200:4321 (192.168.1.200:4321)
writing to stdout
<html>
<head>
 <title>/</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>/</h1>
<tt><pre>
<a href="..">..</a>/
</pre></tt>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

By default, all the containers should be accessible by their names. If not, you need to bind them in a network or link them together.
Look at the docker parameter --link

Example: `docker network connect --link container1:c1 multi-host-network container2`

See more details in the official docker documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/).

Comment: You should not be using `--link` anymore; this is deprecated because it's tremendously brittle (restarting a container breaks the link), and is only available on the default bridge network. It's much better to use the DNS-based mechanisms that were introduced to replace `---link`.